# MySQL - Get three latest dates from tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```sql
create table product (
productid int,
productname varchar(100),
primary key(productid)
)engine=innodb;

create table purchase (
purchaseid int,
fproductid int,
customerage int,
purchasedate date,
purchasetime time,
primary key(purchaseid, fproductid),
foreign key(fproductid) references product(productid)
)engine=innodb;
```

Now I want to get the three latest purchases and the age of the customers who bought them. I've tried this:

```sql
select * 
from product, purchase
where productid = fproductid
and purchasetime in 
 (select max(purchasetime)
 from purchase
 where year(purchasedate) = year(now())
 group by purchaseid
 order by purchasetime)
order by purchasetime limit 3;
```

I'm not getting the correct results with this.

What am I doing wrong? And also is there a way to get them in chronological order from the latest of the three to the earliest?

```
order by purchasetime desc limit 3;
```

is not working for me.

Thank you!

Comment: What means `is not working for me`? Some syntax error? Result are wrong? ALso, why do you are grouping by `purchaseid` on subquery?

Comment: @daniherrera sorry for not making it clear. I get results but they are wrong. I'm not getting the correct purchases. I group by purchaseid because several products can be in the same purchase on the same date and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand relationships.
The query could be much simpler:

```
SELECT * FROM purchase JOIN product ON productid = fproductid
ORDER BY purchasedate DESC, purchasetime DESC LIMIT 3;
```

Note: if purchaseid is an auto_increment PK, it's more efficient to `ORDER BY purchaseid` instead of time

---

One of the reasons why your current query is not returning the results you expect is because of `and purchasetime in (select max(purchasetime)...`

MAX() is returning only one value, so you will get at most one result (unless more orders were made in the same second)

Comment: the_nuts thanks for taking your time. Your query would've probably worked if there was always only one product in the purchase. But a purchase can have more than one product. Therefore I'm trying to group the products into one purchase. That's what the "group by purchaseid" is for.

Comment: Also, it needs to be the latest date too. Otherwise I will just get the latest order by time. It needs to be latest date + latest time. I know I've made it more complicated using both date and time insted of just only using datetime, but I had to use both for the project.

Comment: the_nuts I managed to solve it using a variation of the query you posted. Thank you!

Comment: ah yes, I thought it was a DATETIME field, in that case you could do `ORDER BY purchasedate DESC, purchasetime DESC`. For more products you can do a left join

Comment: the_nuts that solved it. Thank you very much! Working just like I want it now! Thank you